# How can I get the value that comes true with the checkbox checked in the "update" modal popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, bootstrap-modal

When I open a modal to update, I get all the information. But although my checkbox value is true, I cannot display it as checked on the screen.
documentName and documentCode is text value, others are select option.

[image]

```
$('#selectedAddDocName').val(data.techDocInfoList[0].technicalDocumentTypeId).trigger('change');
$('#selectedAddTeknikResim').val(data.techDocInfoList[0].technicalDocumentSubTypeId).trigger('change');
$('#selectedStokGrubu').val(data.techDocInfoList[0].technicalDocumentStockGroupId).trigger('change');

document.getElementById('dokumanKoduInputModal').value = data.techDocInfoList[0].documentCode;
document.getElementById('dokumanAdiInputModal').value = data.techDocInfoList[0].documentName;
```

Comment: set checkbox.checked

Comment: This question has no relation to `c#`

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. where would you suggest me write exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I solved.

```
 if (data.techDocInfoList[0].isSecret == true) {
 document.getElementById("checkSecretModal").checked = true;
    }
 else {
   document.getElementById("checkSecretModal").checked = false;
   }
```